# XCopy to path with a prompt and wildcard

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wildcard, copying

I'm wanting to repurpose a batch file and the latest constraint is the destination location has directories that has a unique identifier and description. I need to prompt for the unique identifer and use a wildcard to bypass the description. for example "\serverB\dest\ID - descriptions\DIR1\DIR2\

```
set DEST="\\serverB\Dest"
set /p UNIQUE ID=Enter ID
echo %UNIQUE_ID%
>NULL xcopy "\\serverA\source\something\file.txt" "%DEST%\%UNIQUE_ID% *\DIR1\DIR2" /i /y
```

Previously i didnt have this issue, so the long directory name wasnt an issue. Now i need to bypass the end component as the directories are not consistent in the description. once i get passed the directory with the unique ID\Desc the remainding subdirectories will be consistent.

```
set DEST="\\serverB\Dest"
set /p UNIQUE ID=Enter ID
echo %UNIQUE_ID%
>NULL xcopy "\\serverA\source\something\file.txt" "%DEST%\%UNIQUE_ID% *\DIR1\DIR2"
```

i get invalid drive specification as the error.

I also dont work in IT or coding for a living, so please be gentle with any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a File Glob in a Directory name unless you are only looking to match a directory name, that is fairly consistent among windows executables.

instead, you can use a `FOR` Loop to match the Directory name using the File Glob for the directory name then save that into a variable and use that in your `XCOPY` Command.

```
@(
  ECHO OFF
  SETLOCAL
  SET "_Src_FilePath=\\serverA\source\something\file.txt"
  SET "_DstPath_Prefix=\\serverB\Dest"
  SET "_DstPath_Postfix=\DIR1\DIR2"
)

SET /P "_UNIQUE_ID=Enter ID: "
IF NOT DEFINED _UNIQUE_ID (
   ECHO. Exiting, you did not provide a Unique ID!
   GOTO :EOF
)
ECHO.ID Provided: "%_UNIQUE_ID%"

REM Get matching Director(y|ies) and copy file(s):

FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%D IN ('
  DIR /AD /B "%_DstPath_Prefix%\%_UNIQUE_ID% *"
') DO (
  ECHO.Matched Directory: "%%D" - Running Copy to: "%_DstPath_Prefix%\%%D%_DstPath_Postfix%"
  >NULL xcopy "%_Src_FilePath%" "%_DstPath_Prefix%\%%D%_DstPath_Postfix%"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the above, it worked great, once i figured out a few things. I havent been entirely forthcoming with what i need to do. basically i have a series of commands which do anything from xcopy, mkdir, rename, delete etc. the common directories are the source and destinations. Once the directory is matched, can this be turned into a variable? ie do it once and reference it moving forward? for example can the %%D be turned into %DEST%, close the command and then use xcopy and others below? I dont know if this can be done, i just cant get it to work using some other cmds

Comment: @3rutu5 Yes!  You can in fact set the directory name to a variable and use it later, howerver it will set the variable to the last match found (or first with an if logic, or you can collect a list of matches in a variable, but then you will still need to loop them later to run the commands against each

Comment: @3rutu5 Alteenatively you can place all of your commands to runinside the loop, or hqve the loop call a sub function to run further commqnds for every match

Comment: for the above i ended up changing the unique_id prompt to another one specified in the Setlocal list, which i could then reference in other items within the batch. If the Unique_ID provides the prompt to use in the Directory look up below, would i be letting the %%d run its course and the under the echo.matched directory then doing a set P=%DEST%?, which can then be substuted into the xcopy and other tasks below? I would prefer to set it at the top under setlocal and then use it within the .bat if i could, from what i see in your response i could? dont sup you have an example?

Comment: @3rutu5  >>I would be interested in if what I mentioned in my other answer could be achieved. ie if I manually punch something in, could I use the first 2 digits in another variable without typing it? I'm thinking if I type in AA-BBB it gets stored as %Unique_ID% and another variable could be created using just the AA part (generally the year) – 3rutu5 Aug 14 at 6:00 << Is that what you mean in the above? If so then you can just use %Unique_ID:~,2% or %Unique_ID:~0,2% (0 can just be left off on some things like this string manip) This will only shwo the first two characters of Unique_ID

Comment: @3rutu5 - Your comments are a little hard to parse, I read this meant to come back and never did, but if you are asking if you can set the %%D variable to a variable which can be used again later, yes, you can do this.  The only concern is that there may be more than one directory matched, in which case you might prefer instead to either Contain all of the further code you would like to perform within this `FOR` `DO` Loop so it will execute on each matched folder, OR `CALL` a sub function with the result if the code is too complex to maintain within the `DO` section of the `FOR` loop.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I did the above basically and after the echo off I used it to set a variable which I think was just called %match% and used it through the batch so far and it seems to work pretty good.

Comment: I will have a look at the partial unique response tonight, what I was hoping was to remove another manual entry step as there are two common characters I was typing in.

Comment: @3rutu5 I always prefer to keep most of it in the script instead of having to re-enter things again and again unless it's going to be used off ad on ad need to be different each time or something.

Comment: works perfectly, just reduced the manual input to just the unique_id now. Much appreicated.

Comment: @3rutu5 Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) in the middle of a path, they can only be used in the very last path element.

To work around that, you could use a [`for /D` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to resolve the wildcard:

```cmd
set "DEST=\\serverB\Dest"
:LOOP
set /P UNIQUE_ID="Enter ID: " || goto :LOOP
echo %UNIQUE_ID%
for /D %%D in ("%DEST%\%UNIQUE_ID% *") do (
    > nul xcopy "\\serverA\source\something\file.txt" "%%~D\DIR1\DIR2"
)
```

There have also a few further things been changed:

- the quoted [`set`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) syntax has been applied, so the quotation marks do no longer become part of the assigned value (see the first line);
- a typo has been fixed, the prompted variable is named `UNIQUE_ID` but not `UNIQUE ID`;
- it is demonstrated how to detect whether or not the user entered something in the `Enter ID` prompt by using [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html);
- the null device in Windows is called [`nul`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) but not `null`;

Comment: Thanks, for that. Does the amended code allow me to use %%~D Further in the batch for other commands? I think I need to as I've just noticed i had used this directory within attached scripts as well, which the batch triggers. Sorry I'm a AutoCAD drafter and this will copy checklists and run some job specific scripts to a drawing. It is probably more complicated than it needs to be, but something written years ago and I've forgotten how it was originally done

Comment: Previous workplace had a fairly standard directory setup, but this one has a unique number and description, which is causing me some grief. Before I would set/p and prompt for a project number and it would substitute it below. I have managed to do that still in parts by promoting and then using the set variable within the unique_id one. If I could then use the "matched" directory as another variable I could have this process sorted moving forward.

Comment: You're welcome! The `%%~D` can only be used in the loop context, hence within the parenthesised block after `do`; but since there should only be one matching directory (as far as I understood), you could in the loop do `set "MATCHED=%%~D"` and use the variable `%MATCHED%` elsewhere in the script...

Comment: I will give that a try tonight, but I think that is exactly what I was chasing :) thanks a lot guys for the help, much appreciated

Comment: Glad to be of service! Please consider to upvote helpful answers and to accept the one that completely satisfied you! Read [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) why this is important! Thank you!

Comment: ok, i got impaitent and gave it a go                                                                
`code` :LOOP
SET PROJ_DEF=%PROJNO%
FOR /D %%E in ("%PROJECTS%\%YEAR%\%PROJ_DEF% *") do (
set matched=%%E
)
>NUL mkdir "%PROJECT%\%YEAR%\%MATCHED%\%PROJECTS_END%\Z_TEST
:: `code`                                                                                                                                 ok so i gave it a go and it didnt work, so did i understand correctly by placing the set variable under the "DO" function?

Comment: What it appears to do is set the variable as "%%E and create a directory in the %PROJECTS%\%YEAR% section which is based on the source directory it is coming from so could be a bit of error on my behalf.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't quite follow! It's difficult to understand code in comments. What exactly does not work? what happens and what should happen?

Comment: Sorry I was having troubles putting the code in the comment, then ended up working it would and putting an answer in by mistake. In short it all works.

Comment: I would be interested in if what I mentioned in my other answer could be achieved. ie if I manually punch something in, could I use the first 2 digits in another variable without typing it? I'm thinking if I type in AA-BBB it gets stored as %Unique_ID% and another variable could be created using just the AA part (generally the year)